# How to remove folded battery from phone without starting a fire?

Tags: batteries, safety, lithium-ion, cellphone

I was trying to replace the battery in my phone, but since it was very well glued to the phone, I accidentally folded it in half. This immediately caused some dark brown smoke to come out from it, so I took it outside.

A few hours later, it seems to have stopped making smoke, and the bottom folded part looks very swollen.

[image]

I'd like to take it out, but I'm scared it will do something like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JebU6ZKA9oI). Is there anything I can do to avoid it from catching fire? Also, are the fumes it releases dangerous?

Comment: since i have no idea about fumes, i would consider the fumes dangerous. .... maybe put it in a plastic bag and fill the bag with helium so there is no oxygen, then peel off the battery ... just a thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a bloated Li-ion/Li-Po battery is very dangerous and should be handled with lot of care.Usually people would discard if the battery is in a dangerous position to be handled. I'm going to assume that your phone is expensive and you wouldn't want to discard it.

Since, you have mentioned that after keeping it out for a while it has stopped making smoke you could do the following:
1.Wear full sleeve cloths, thick fire safety gloves(most important) and some kind of face protection.
2.Always use some kind of prying tool/spudger that is used in mobile repair to remove batteries.

Something like in video could occur if the battery has some charge left in it.

Overall, its a real risk trying to repair the phone. Proceed with caution before you attempt to. Also keep it in a safe place where it wouldn't cause fire.

http://ehs.whoi.edu/ehs/occsafety/LithiumBatterySafetyGuideSG10.pdf

Comment: Face protection doesn't need to be something that you wear. You could put the phone behind something transparent that you can reach around. Wear safety goggles in addition.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Thanks for mentioning that. It didn't cross my mind. Working behind a fiber glass might help.

Comment: @user485573 Glad you managed to get it out. Just make sure to keep that battery in a tight strong container and dispose it properly. It could still have some juice to start a fire.

Comment: I am always wondering how do you "properly dispose" a battery like this? If you drop it off on a disposal site and it starts a file in a pile of other batteries, that wouldn't be good.